# Getting persistent data to components

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to know what im doing wrong cos i need persistent data from a service and get that data on my artist and album component. I don´t paste the album component 'cos it's the same. Im trying to get artist, albums, tracks, etc... Im sorry if it's a basic question but im new on angular and typescript. Thanks for reading anyaway!.

```
// artist.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SpotifyService } from './spotify.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ArtistService {

     artist: any;
     tracks: any;
     albums: any;
     artistRel: any;

    constructor(private _spotify: SpotifyService) {}

    getArtistDetail(id: string) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(this._spotify.getArtista(id).subscribe(artist => {
                console.log(artist, 'Artista');
                return this.artist = artist;
            }));
        }).then(resp => {
            this._spotify.getTop(id).map((resp:any) => resp.tracks)
                .subscribe(tracks => {
                    console.log(tracks, 'Tracks');
                        return this.tracks = tracks;
                    });

        }).then(resp => {
            this._spotify.getAlbumsArtist(id).map((resp: any) => resp.items)
                .subscribe(albums => {
                    console.log(albums, 'Albums');
                    return this.albums = albums;
                });
        }).then(resp => {
            this._spotify.getRelatedArtists(id).map((resp: any) => resp)
                .subscribe(related => {
                    console.log(related, 'Artists related');
                    return this.artistRel = related;
                });
        }).catch(error => console.log(error, 'Something Happened...'));
    }

}
```

> Blockquote

```
// artist.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ArtistService } from '../../services/artist.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-artist',
  templateUrl: './artist.component.html'
})
export class ArtistComponent implements OnInit {

  artist: {};

  constructor(public _artistService: ArtistService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.map(params => params['id']).subscribe(id => {
      this._artistService.getArtistDetail(id);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Im trying this way..but it doesn't work
    this.artist = this._artistService.artist;
  }
}
```

> Blockquote

```
// artist.component.html

<div class="container top30" *ngIf="artist">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img [src]="artist.images | sinfoto" class="img-thumbnail  rounded-circle">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <h1>{{ artist.name }}</h1>
            <hr>

            <a [href]="artist.external_urls.spotify" target="_blank" class="btn btn-outline-success">Abrir Spotify</a>
            <button [routerLink]="['/search']" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Regresar</button>


        </div>


    </div>
<!-- Desplegar albumes -->
<div class="container top30">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"
             *ngFor="let album of albums">
             <img [src]="album.images | sinfoto" 
                  class="img-thumbnail puntero"
                  [routerLink]="['/album', album.id]"
                  >

             <p>{{ album.name }}</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work means? Are you getting any errors in console or just data not shown on UI?

Comment: Right.. Sorry... Does it means that the data doesnt shown on UI. The service works just fine, i get every console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a getter (so, you needn't use ngOnInit)

```
//artist{}  //<--comment this, use a getter
get artist()
{
    return this._artistService.artist
}
```

Anyway, you must considered use Observables and your service return Observables (or Promise), not store the data

Using Observables, your service can be like

```
getArtistDetail(id: string) {
     return forkJoin([
         this._spotify.getArtista(id),
         this._spotify.getAlbumsArtist(id),
         this._spotify.getRelatedArtists(id)])
}
```

In your component

```
ngOnInit() {
    //I put the subscribe to params in ngOnInit

    this.route.params.map(params => params['id']).subscribe(id => {
      this._artistService.getArtistDetail(id).subscribe(res=>
      {  //res is an array
         console.log(res);
         this.artist=res[0];
         this.albums=res[1];
         this.related=res[2]; 
      })
    });
 }
```

Comment: I've been trying a lot of thing... I tried Observable to subscribe on components but i couldnt get it... Im learning about it... And  thank you so much ! it worked with getter!

Comment: @Nacho, I update the answer using Observables, take a look it

Comment: Thank you so much for the anwser!, didnt know about forkjoin. Im gonna study about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be async nature of your code. In constructor of your component, you made an async call to get data. Next ngOnInit() function gets executed, you're trying to get data which is not yet present because async call has not yet returned and set the result. This line

```
this.artist = this._artistService.artist;
```

will return null because this._artistService.artist is not yet set to data by async call.

Comment: Right, thats why i console.log on artist.component i get undefined.. Thanks but i want to know how to access that data cos i really dont know another way

Comment: You need to assign this.artist to observable/Promise, so when value comes in, it gets assigned to it.